# Installer Oracle 11g windows 64 bit doesn't work

Tags: windows, oracle11g, installation

This one drives me crazy, I am installing Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Windows 64 bit version. Because Express edition doesn't work on win7.

Link to download is: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html

In total there are 2 files, using 7zip I have unzipped them in one folder. Folder is called 'database' containing:

- doc
- install
- response
- stage
- setup
- welcome

I double clicked on setup, passed installation option where they ask me to provide email address to be informed of security issues. I selected 'Create and configure a database'. And in the next step where they ask for type of installation I chose 'Desktop Class'. After I clicked on 'Next' the installer just closes and installation is stopped..

Any idea what might be the cause? I have the rights, I am using a clean new laptop, WIN7 64 bit, installed JDK.

Comment: There should be a log from the installer, which will hopefully indicate why it exited; unless it really crashed, in which case it might still give a clue from what it was doing last.

Comment: If you purpose is some developing/testing/learning why not use [pre-built Oracle VM images](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=tumblr#dbapp)? You just need to install Virualbox and download the image file.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin, that is a very good suggestion. I actually did have one installed before my windows got whipped but wanted to try it 'local' since VM was Linux. I will close this question.

Comment: @Danny I will add it as an answer if you don't mind. Please accept it to mark your question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you purpose is some developing/testing/learning why not use [pre-built Oracle VM images](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=tumblr#dbapp)? You just need to install Virualbox and download the image file.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 11G Express Edition is officially available on 64-bit versions of Windows (Finally!).

[Oracle 11G Express Edition Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I quote:

> Because Express edition doesn't work on win7.

It actually works. 
Just right click on setup and click "run as administrator". Ignore any error message.
It worked on win7 64bit and Windows Server 2008 R2 (of course 64bit).